# Make an SQL request that builds a 'result cache' without returning results

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, caching

I have a stateless webserver that requires 2 sets of user input to do a computation:

Page 1: GET INPUT A
Page 2: GET INPUT B
Page 3: Results calculated form user input A and B

It so happens that the bottleneck in my application is a lookup related to user input A.

As a speed up hack I make the SQL request on A that "Page 3" later does, while I wait for the user to input B such that when the user clicks submit on 'Page 2', the lookup result from 'data A' is already cached (saving impatient users 2-5 seconds).

#### My question

Is it possible to make my SQL lookup in such a way that the server does the query and caches it with out returning anything, as I only need it to be in the cache to make the final request 2-5 sec faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result is not big the best would be to save the user state in a server side session.

---

Update:

That is one of the cases (multiple web servers vs single db server) where a db stored session fits.

Save the result:

```
insert into temp_result (session_id, a, b)
select %(session_id)s, a, b
from t
```

Retrieve it:

```
select a, b
from t
where session_id = %(session_id)s
```

When the session expires or after a timeout delete it.

Comment: our server is stateless, and we would like to keep it that way :), and thus we only save state information (data) client side, the result is megabytes, so saving it client side is out of the question

Comment: @azorius As I understand you are talking about stateless **web** server, not the db server. If that is the case then the session state can be kept at the db server. It will last as long as the session. Can you share a link about the scenario you are envisioning? The HTTP protocol is stateless by nature. I'm just trying to understand what you are up to.

Comment: we are using a self build stateless python framework to handle incomming requests and returning html, the way I do it now is as follows, a class checks user input A, if it is valid it sends him to 'page 2' after sending him to page 2 it does a SQL request (SELECT * from X where ...;), waits for it to return, when the sql request returns the request class instance dies, I would like to write an SQL statement that is evaluated by the database but who returns 'null' to my class rather than a huge datatype I drop 1 nano second later :)

Comment: the database is hundreds of gigabytes large and we have 6 different webservers that all 'share access' to it

Comment: @azorius Stash the cached result in memcached or redis for quick return when needed then.

Comment: I appriciate your help, the disk cash that comes with postgresql is so fast that I do not need any additional software, the returned data structure is not really a bottleneck and our servers load are usaly below 50% ram and cpu, therefore I was mostly interested in whether there were a SQL idom that would allow you to request a server to only cash the result for future use with out accually returning the result, because that would be a useful think to know the next time I run into this 'problem' :)

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a result cache, so you can't pre-warm it.

It *does* have a disk cache. To pre-warm that, you can just run `SELECT` statements that discard the results. Use a PL/PgSQL `PERFORM` statement, a pointless aggregate, etc. A search for "postgresql pre-warm cache" may be informative.

You may also want to look into *materialized views*. PostgreSQL doesn't support materialized views yet, but you can simulate them with triggers and scripts. There are patches in progress to add materialized view support in progress too.

Comment: materialized views sounds very cool but is overkill overkill for our project :), I have tried to google the PERFORM statement but I cannot find any good documentation on how to use it (I am fairly SQL illiterate)... how would I run a command like "SELECT * FROM X where a=x1 and b=x2; such that the cash gets warmed but the result dosen't get returned?